# Asp.net dropdown value nothing

Tags: asp.net

Using SQL Server and ASP.NET.

I am populating a drop down list on a form from one table sat NAME, ID... where dropdown text=NAME and dropdown value=ID...

Form is having field storing this ID field value. (act as foreign key referencing above table having NAME, ID fields)

and 1st item in dropdown list is : Text='Select'. What value should be specified for this item, so that if nothing is selected (i.e. text = select) then in database it should not store anything.

If I use empty string it takes zero as vlaue, if I use NULL then it stores NULL value.

Answer (score 2):

the "SELECT" value in the prev drop down shoule be -1.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Dilip..assuming that your ID is of integer type, you should consider using -1 as your 'null/nothing' value i.e set the 'Select' dropdownlist item's value to -1...just remember to do the same in your item, edit and insert templates.

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign -1 (or) 0 to the "select" as value, you need to validate in

client-side to prevent the storing the those values into the database.

If the dropdown list is not mandatory - then validate on the server side or Stored proc,

if the coming value for insert or update is -1 or 0 then store it as NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store nothing in database. Either it is empty string (if ID field is `char` type) or null (as it should not be as foreign key is involved). You need to check before posting to database what is selected from dropdown and send the correct value to database.